# How to convert Spark Dataframe to JSON using json4s, in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, json4s

Trying to convert a dataframe to a JSON string and the output is just {}. Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

This is just a test but full Dataframe schema I need to use is 800+ columns so I don't want to have to specify each field specifically in the code if possible! Code runs in a locked down corporate environment so I can't write or read files to the system, has to be string output only.

```
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.write
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val test = spark.sql("SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM myTable LIMIT 2");

println("Output:");
write(test);


Output:
res12: String = {}
```

To add insult to injury, I could use the built in toJSON function (from scala.util.parsing.json._) but our corporate environment has set spark.sql.jsonGenerator.ignoreNullFields to True and it can't be changed but the output has to include null fields - hoping json4s can oblige :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

That's because `spark.sql(...)` returns a DataFrame, and all instance variables of `DataFrame` are private, so your parser will basically just ignore them. You can try this:

```scala
case class PrivateStuff(private val thing: String)

write(PrivateStuff("something"))
// ourputs {}
```

So you can't just convert a whole DataFrame to JSON, what you can do instead, is to collect your data (which returns `Array[Row]` or `List[Row]`) and try to convert each row into Scala objects, since the result of converting rows to JSON is not probably what you want, and then, use the write function:

```scala
case class YourModel(x1: String, ...)
object YourModel {
  def fromRow(row: Row): Option[YourModel] = // conversion logic here
}

val myData: Array[YourModel] = spark.sql("SELECT ...")
  .collect()
  .map(YourModel.fromRow)
  .collect { case Some(value) => value }

write(myData)
```

## Update

---

After your explanations about the size of the rows, it doesn't make sense to create case classes, you can use the `json` method of the `Row` class in order to achieve that (and it doesn't care about `spark.sql.jsonGenerator.ignoreNullFields`):

```scala
val test = spark.sql("SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM myTable LIMIT 2")

val jsonDF = test.map(_.json)
```

This is a dataframe of JSON objects, you can collect them, save them to files, show them, basically anything you can do with a dataframe.

Comment: thanks. I'm new to Scala/Spark, could you give an example of conversion logic? I have 800+ columns in each row (mostly string, some bigint). Also what's the "x1: String, ..." bit in the first line? Thanks

Comment: @AlexKerr 800+ columns or rows? if it's columns, that's too huge to be fit into a class, then we should consider using another approach!

Comment: yes 831 columns :) And output from the query itself would be a few thousand rows. That's what I need as a JSON file...! Thanks

Comment: @AlexKerr Yeah, I did an update to the answer.

Comment: thanks, looks good and I tried this but unfortunately the corporate environment I'm in runs Spark 2.4.0 and .json is only available since 3.0. I am attempting to get it working by using 850+ fields in a case class....